# Vuetify / DataTable: Changing style for 'show-group-by' button?

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

I want to use the default grouping function in the vuetify datatable.
It works fine, but I want to change the default button style for grouping and replace it with an icon.
Is that possible? If I inspect the button in the dev tools, it just shows `<span>group</span>`.
Found only this in the docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#grouped-rows

Edit: By now I know what I would like. I am looking for the default template for the `v-slot:header`. This is where the button I mentioned above is generated that starts the grouping.

Comment: You can use `<template v-slot:top>` to customize the html content in the table header

Comment: Oh thanks, never thought about that. :D Is there a way to see the default component of vuetify which is handling the header? So I could copy paste the default and just change the group by button?

Comment: yes you can, try using `v-slot:group` and more specific details can be viewed in the document.

Comment: I found a similar question - [vuetify-2-grouped-data-table-with-customized-group-header-and-item-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987223/vuetify-2-grouped-data-table-with-customized-group-header-and-item-rows)

Comment: Hehe, I found that too after you gave me the tipp. :) That really helped, thanks. Just one more question. I wanted to know, if I can look up the default `<template>` of an vuetify component. Only the variables/props are listed in their documentation.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you mean, do you mean the default template slot or no slot? If the `v-slot` specified in the document is not passed in, the template may be filtered and not rendered.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry for the late response. I wish I could look up the default "template" for one of these slots. Something like M3HDI posted in the answer below. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `group.header` slot and provide your own template for the group header including the toggle button and use the `toggle` method from the props like :

```
<template v-slot:group.header="{ group, headers, toggle, isOpen }">
  <td :colspan="headers.length">
     <v-btn @click="toggle" x-small icon :ref="group">
         <v-icon v-if="isOpen">mdi-plus</v-icon>
         <v-icon v-else>mdi-minus</v-icon>
     </v-btn>
     <span class="mx-5 font-weight-bold">{{ group }}</span>
  </td>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for this example. :) In the meantime, I got something similar. But I like yours more and will stay with that. By now I know what I would like. I am looking for the template for the `v-slot:header`. This is where the button is generated that starts the grouping.

Comment: YW mate. I didn't fully understand what you want to do with the `header` slot , but if you could explain a bit more , I'm happy to help if needed .

Comment: Ah yes, sure. If you activate the `show-group-by` prop for the vuetify datatable, it will generate a button on every column title to toggle the grouping. The button itself is just a `<span>group</span>` and I would like to change this button into a real button with an icon. I think I need to customize the hole header template for that, but I want to leave the rest as it is and I think I could do that, if I knew how the default header template looks like.

Comment: for that you need to use the 'header' slot and hide the default header when you're using groupBy. the props and the method for `show-group-by` is already a part of the `header` slot. I made a simplistic Pen for you that should help you do this and anything extra for this matter. here's the link: https://codepen.io/devisshortfordevil/pen/VwaPBGK

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. :D Thank you so much.

Comment: For anyone else that come here with google, I ended up styling the **"group"** button using css `th[role="columnheader"] > span:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: aqua !important;
}`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to replace the default sort icon and the group button (which just appears to be a span tag with the text 'group' inside) in the v-data-table headers row by using the `hide_default_header` prop on the `v-data-table` and then replacing the hidden headers row by using the `header` slot. [v-data-table docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots)

```html
<template v-slot:header="props">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <template v-for="header in props.props.headers">
                <th :key="header.value">
                    <span>{{ header.text }}</span>
                    <v-btn @click.stop="props.on.sort(header.value)" icon><v-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</v-icon></v-btn>
                    <v-btn @click.stop="props.on.group(header.value)" icon><v-icon>flip_to_back</v-icon></v-btn>
                </th>
           </template>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone using the Vuetify 2 here is the [code that worked for me](https://codepen.io/Toscan00/pen/yLPOMoO?editors=101)

```
<template v-slot:header="{ props: { headers }, on } ">
  <tr>
    <th v-for="header in headers" :class="header.class" :width="header.width" >
        {{header.text}}
        <v-icon @click="on.group(header.value)"> {{ header.icon }} </v-icon>
    </th>
  </tr>
</template>
```